# How to collect GCLogs

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-dump

I am new to G C and heaps. Can anyone suggest how can I collect G  C Logs? I have properly set environment. I am able to collect heap information by running jmap command, when I type commands such as `-Xloggc:<confluence-home>/logs/gc.log`
it shows error xx parameters are not recognized.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have to give xx paramter `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`

Example:

```
java -Xloggc:./memory.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails Memory
```